# "npm install -D" installs package using a URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

For instance, if I run `npm i babel-core -D` then it installs the following to `package.json`:

```
"babel-core": "https://registry.npmjs.org/babel-core/-/babel-core-6.13.2.tgz",
```

When it should be a version number instead. I'm using node v6.3.1 and npm v3.10.6. I *think* this started happening when I upgraded from node v4 to node v6. I searched online for help but couldn't find anything. (Like "npm installs to package.json with url").

How do I get it to use a version number instead? I've had this happen with other packages too. But not all.